# Why is there no ripple when a checkbox is in the same layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

Whenever I am creating a layout, it has a ripple (see image). If I add a checkbox, the ripple just doesn't show. I would like it to show a ripple even though there is a checkbox. How can I do so?

Ripple:
[image]

No Ripple (But with checkbox)
[image]

Comment: More details on how the layout is setup should be added here to help others debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Enable Ripple:**
You can achieve this by adding the following to the parent LinearLayout:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

**Disable Ripple:** (As suggested by @Caspain Caldion)

```
android:background="#ffffffff"
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not add ripple to background use foreground instead.

```
android:background="#ffffffff"
android:foreground="#ffffffff"
```

Comment: Any Idea how I can disable the ripple? `android:clickable="false"` does not seem to work..

Comment: try.android:foreground="@null"

Comment: android:background="@null" try that as well. worked for me once.

Comment: i also tried this hack. android:background="#ffffffff"

Comment: `android:background="#ffffffff"` seems to work! Thanks